# Inconsistency with generating function? Problem with distinguishing between sum of 2 trials of X and 2X

Tags: probability

$$X\sim Po(\lambda)$$
$$ X_1+X_2\sim Po(2\lambda) $$
$$2X\sim Po(2\lambda)$$ It is clear that $X_1+X_2\neq2X$.

$G_{X_1+X_2}(t)=E(t^{x_1+x_2})=E(t^{x_1}t^{x_2})=E(t^{x_1})E(t^{x_2})=(G_X(t))^2=e^{2\lambda(t-1))}$ assuming independence.

However, $G_{2X}(t)=E[(t^2)^x)]=G_{X}(t^2)=e^{\lambda(t^2-1)}$ which is not the correct generating function for a variable that follows $Po(2\lambda)$. Why is this so?

Also how do you distinguish between $X_1+X_2$ and $ 2X$ for distributions like the negative binomial, geometric and binomial? e.g. if $X\sim NB(n,p)$/$X\sim Geo(p)$/$X\sim B(n,p)$, what would $X_1+X_2$ follow and how different is it compared to $2X$?

Comment: The two $X$ in $X+X = 2X$ are clearly not independent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that if $X_1$ and $X_2$ are identically distributed and independent random variables, then
$$
var(X_1 + X_2) = 2\sigma^2_X,
$$
however, 
$$
var(2X_1) = 2^2var(X_1) = 4 \sigma^2_X.
$$
Namely, $2X_1$ is intuitively an "enlargement" of your random variable, thus its expected value and variance are twice as larger as of the original, while the sum of two independent random variables has a different distribution. The distribution of $X_1 + X_2$ can be found by convolution, where for $2X_1$ you'll need only the transformation formula as you don't add up different random variable, but only linearly transform the original one.

Answer (score 1):

Your claim that $2X$ is a poisson random variable under the assumption $X\sim\text{Po}(\lambda)$ is incorrect. If it was then
$$
Var(2X)=E(2X)\implies 4\lambda=2\lambda \implies \lambda=0 
$$
which is a contradiction. Also
$$
M_{2X}(t)=Ee^{t(2X)}=Ee^{(2t)X}=M_X(2t)=\exp(e^{\lambda(2t-1)})
$$
where $X\sim\text{Po}(\lambda)$.